# How to keep the order of words while reading a right to left text pdf

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a text from a pdf file 
(with right to left language) 
using java (code below)
    sometimes because it's a right to 
left language - 
the order of the words 
changes after my try to break the lines.

For example:

> טלפון: טלפון1 דואר:דואר1

Became:

> דואר1 : דואר טלפון1  טלפון:

```java
public void test(){
     PDFParser parser = null;
            PDDocument pdDoc = null;
            COSDocument cosDoc = null;
            PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;

            String parsedText = "";
            try {
                parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(new File(file1), "r"));
                parser.parse();
                cosDoc = parser.getDocument();

                pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();            
                pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);

             //separator
                pdfStripper.setWordSeparator(" ");

                pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            //get count of pages
                int pages = pdDoc.getPages().getCount();
                pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
                pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);
                parsedText = parsedText + pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
                if(pages>1){
                   //
                }

                StringTokenizer lines = new StringTokenizer(parsedText, "\n");
                return lines.getTokenList();
            } catch (){
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question : If you read from right to left, isn't it normal that the order of the words change ?

Comment: If you reading from right to left, your parsedText should be 
parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc) + parsedText;
That's what I'd imagine

Comment: i mean that i want to get the same line as in the pdf for example sometimes it ok and sometimes the order gets mixed. if the line is שלום אחד שתיים i want it like this and not אחד שלום שתיים

Answer (score 1):

Try to use simple invert:

```
public String invert(String s){
    String arr[] = s.split(" ");
    int len = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        String temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[len - i - 1];
        arr[len - i - 1] = temp;
    }

    return Arrays.stream(arr)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

Using example:

```
System.out.println(invert("1 2 3 4 5");
```

Result:

> 5 4 3 2 1

Also, you should be considering another delimiter signs (enter, tabulation, comma...)